# Visual/look (not functional!) unit testing in iOS

Tags: ios, unit-testing, automation, ui-testing

I'm developing some custom UI controls, and I'd like to unit test them *visually*; that is, the driving test data should simply be user interaction (taps, swipes, etc.), and the passing the test means the correct thing is rendered on the device.

I've looked at some existing UI test environments (e.g. UIAutomation scripts), but they solve a different problem -- they generate a sequence of UI events and test against app states they cause.  That's one level up from what I'm talking about -- they assume the UI controls work as designed, and don't take the look of the UI into account at all.

I'd like to generate a user interaction as a series of taps and swipes, record the result on the device, and compare the result against a desired output (an image or video).

Is there anything out there which does this?